# Pygame double jump

Tags: python, pygame

I have nearly given up, so I need help.
I'm trying to make a simple platformer that has double jumps...
I keep running in circles trying to find something that works
The best Idea I have so far is to compare the number of ticks, but each time I get some idea, I somehow manage to screw it all up and I don't know how...
is there an easy way?

please ignore any unnecessary variables this is just an example

```
Clock=pygame.time.Clock()

t=0
a=0
b=0
f=0
m=0

while True:
    Clock.tick(180)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:       
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_SPACE and b==0:
                movey=-1
                a=1
                t=pygame.time.get_ticks()
            if event.key==K_SPACE and b==1:
                f=pygame.time.get_ticks()
                if f<=t+238:
                    a=1
                else:
                    pass
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key==K_SPACE and b==0 and a==1:
                a=0
                b=1
            if event.key==K_SPACE and b==1 and a==1:
                m=1
                b=3
                s=y
    if m==1:
        y+=movey
        if y==s-32:
            m==0

    elif y<=312 and movey==-1:
        movey=+1
    elif y==344 and movey==+1:
        movey=0
        a=0
        b=0
    else:
        y+=movey
```

Right now this is the one I'm trying....

Comment: Do you have single jump implemented? You add to *y velocity*. After that, you can toggle a bool 'can_double_jump` if you hit jump again. That will reset when you touch ground.

Comment: ...Let's pretend I don't have a clue what you mean...Like, could you give a longer explanation?

Comment: please help, anyone...

Comment: @user2154113 what he's basically doing is making a variable `jump` and giving it three states.  When it is in the first, you are on the ground and can jump.  When it is in the second, you are in the air and have not done the double jump yet, and therefore can still jump.  The third, you have already double jumped, and you can't jump until you hit the ground.

Answer (score 3):

```
g = -1  # gravity
floor = 0  # where frog stands


class Frog():  # say you have a frog
    def __init__(self):
        self.y = 0  # distance from ground
        self.y_speed = 0  # speed
        self.jumping = 0  # jumping status

    def jump(self):
        if self.jumping == 0:
            self.y_speed = 9  # a big jump
            self.jumping = 1  # change jumping status
        # I want the small jump available only when falling
        elif self.jumping == 1 and self.y_speed <= 0:
            self.y_speed = 5  # a small one
            self.jumping = 2  # change jumping status

    def update(self):  # this is called by mainloop
        self.y_speed += g  # change the acceleration
        self.y = max(self.y + self.y_speed, floor)  # don't want fall off
        if self.y == 0:  # on the ground again!
            self.jumping = 0  # reset jump
            self.y_speed = 0  # reset speed
```

Comment: Pretty much what I did, but mine runs alone.

Comment: really nice example, you could define states at the beginning so it is easier to read without the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Two examples:

- single jump http://pastebin.com/ZLuPBg7k
- double jump http://pastebin.com/uwK5wPM1

You can force a minimum time between double jumps, but I left that out to simplify the example. Ask if you have any other questions.

Comment: I think this has sent me in the right direction, still working it out though

Answer (score -2):

would it not be easier to use a counter ? just set a counter variable = 0 within your player, then define your jump and set counter += 1. then say if counter < 2 then you can jump. no ?